# xCode and C++ arays. How this is possible? Declaring an array without size in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, xcode

So I'm creating an empty array and assigning to its first 4 elements some values. I'm copying the same code into Visual Studio and the program doesn't work because it can't understand the line. So how in C++ declare empty arrays?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double inTotal(double quartersQuantity, double dimesQuantity, double 
nickelsQuantity, double penniesQuantity) {


double total = 0.25 * quartersQuantity + 0.10 * dimesQuantity + 0.05 * 
nickelsQuantity + 0.01 * penniesQuantity;

return total;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

string coinNames[] = {"quarters", "dimes", "nickels", "pennies"};
double coinQuantity[] = {};
int counter = 0;

for (string values : coinNames) {
    cout << "How many " << values << " do you have\n";
    cin >> coinQuantity[counter];
    counter++;

}

double total = inTotal(coinQuantity[0], coinQuantity[1], 
coinQuantity[2], coinQuantity[3]);
cout << "Your dollar value is " << total << " dollars." << endl;



return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The code you show is invalid: there is no such thing as a non-dynamic zero size array in standard C++. When you use a language extension that allows it, you have Undefined Behavior by using any item, as you do. Instead of raw arrays just use `std::vector`, which can expand as needed when you use e.g. `v.push_back( blah );`.

Comment: SO but how come the program in xCode works fine?

Comment: Possible UB includes that the program does what you intended. Until, by Murphy's law, it's critical that it works. Then it produces a big fat scrolling banner saying that the persons you are doing a demo for, those interested buyers, are ugly and dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise array this way.

```
int coinQuantity[4];  // declare the array
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // ...initialize it
{
    coinQuantity[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So how in C++ declare empty arrays?

As "Cheers and hth. - Alf" wrote:
*there is no such thing as a non-dynamic zero size array in standard C++.*

But you don't actually want an *empty* array; in your case, you need an array `coinQuantity` with the same number of elements as the array `coinNames` has. In Visual Studio you can define it by writing

```
double coinQuantity[_countof(coinNames)] = {};
```

In environments which don't predefine the macro `_countof()`, you can define that by writing

```
#define _countof(array) (sizeof array / sizeof *array)
```